# How can find points such that the tangent fails to exist?

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $F(x,y)=0$ and $F(x,y)$ be polynomial in $\mathbb R$.

How can  find points such that  the tangent fails to exist ?

Comment: By equating $grad(F)$ to infinity componentwise for any $F$. In particular if $F$ is a polynomial then there won't be any such point.

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande - ' In particular if F is a polynomial then there won't be any such point.' It is not true, because $y^3-x^2=0$.

Comment: In general $y^3−x^2+a=0$ has tangent iff  $a \neq 0$ .

Answer (score 1):

By [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#General_formula_for_derivative_of_implicit_function) we have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}} =-\frac{F_x}{F_y} $$

> Let $F(a,b)=0$ , Now if the tangent in the point $s=(a,b)$ fails to exist , then it's necessary that $F_x=F_y=0$.

Because if one of the $F_x$ or $F_y$  isn't zero , then one of the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{dx}{dy}$ exists like circle : $y^2+x^2-1=0$ at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.
Example of singular point : $(0,0)$ in $y^3-x^2=0$ . Because $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{3y^2}$ and  $2x=0=3y^2$.
But this criterion($F_x=F_y=0$) is not sufficient . For example $x^5-y^3=0$ in $(0,0)$ .

Comment: What about dealing with $F(x,y)=x^2+y^4+1=0$. Would you try to differentiate it like that? I don't think so. :-)

Comment: @S.Snape What's the problem? Your example hasn't any solution .

Comment: @2000 - Which theorem says that, Let $F(a,b)=0$ , Now if the tangent in the point $s=(a,b)$ fails to exist , then it's necessary that $F_x=F_y=0$. ?

Comment: @2000 - Can we say that, points such that the tangent fails to exist ,are finite?

Comment: @H.S Of course. Because $F_x$ and $F_y$ are polynomial , and [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) says  number of common points, or intersection points, of two plane algebraic curves X and Y is equal to the product of their degrees .

Comment: @2000 - Thanks for this answer, Therefore, Is it true that every algebraic curve is a ${C^\infty }$ piecewise curve?

Comment: @H.S Now it's clear.

Comment: @2000: What I was trying to say is "we cannot differentiate any polynimoial without checking if it has make sense or not!". The OP asked about any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$ so, it would be better note him "If $F(x,y)=0$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$ implicitly then ...." and $...$ is your answer. That's it! :-)